# Push notification certificate for multiple customers

Tags: ios, notifications, push

Here is my problem.

I have a product .NET (not iOS related at all) that has multiple customers and each customer will install it himself.
 I have an iOS app that use Apple push notifications.

My .NET product is the server side provider for iOS notifications.
My customers install .NET product and iOS app.

But during .NET product installation, i need to give then the certificate with which the .NET product can call APNS.

Since .NET product calls APNS, i need to ship the APNS certificate with Private key.

Is that secure? Typical iOS app push providers (server side code) resides at one place (typically with the developer of that product and running at one place or cloud), but my .NET product is on customer's site

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like the simplest solution would be for your .Net product to use some other server to send the push notifications rather than sending directly - you could then handle the authentication of your .Net product to the other server any way you like and wouldn't have to expose the APNS certificate.

Comment: Do all the users of the .NET product send push notifications to all the users of your iOS app? Or does each pusher push to a unique subset of users?

Comment: I have exactly the same situation. It is not secure to deploy the iOS push certificate to every customer, because you do not have control of the security there. Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: The temp solution i found is to have the APNS cert password protected and then package it in my server side code and deploy it my Applications programdata from which server side will pick it up.   The long term solution i am planning is: Recently, iOS has enabled to  create multiple APNS certificates for a single AppId. So, what i am planning to do is enable a setting in my server side application where they can enter the location of the APNS certificate. Then, for each customer, I can generate a separate APNS certificate and give them the certificate. I will still be responsible for renewal